# Unable to install a specific version of django on virtualenv

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I have been trying to install django 1.8 on virtualenv, i performed the following steps:

1. changed to my project directory
2. changed to scripts folder of virtual environment which I created
3. activated the virtual env
4. typed command: `pip install django == 1.8`

Nothing worked

also, tried `pip install django` and `easy_install django`, however, none worked.

Could you please help me out ?

Comment: What is the output of `pip install django == 1.8`?

Comment: @Abu-- Hi Abu, I did not get any output. The cursor kept on blinking.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this command:

sudo pip install django==1.8

Comment: @A J--- I am on windows, and I tried runas/env pip install django, it did not work.

Comment: I think first you need to install easy_install then install pip with that, and try to install Django.

Answer (score 1):

One problem could be that the command line doesn't tokenize the command correctly. Try the following (with the quotes around the requirement specifier):

```
pip install "django==1.8"
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you haven't shared the output error, I suggest some actions:

1. Try to use the absolute path or add the path of your pip installation to your PATH system variable:

Go to CMD change the python instalation directory `C:\>cd \Python27\Scripts` and type `C:\Python27\Scripts>pip -h`

If works well you can use the absolute path `C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install "django==1.8"` or add the path of your pip installation to your PATH variable using the command above:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python27\Scripts"

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
```

2. Another attempt is updating pip scripts using easy_install

   (FlaskEnv27) E:\Projects\FlaskEnv27\Scripts>easy_install pip
   Searching for pip
   Best match: pip 1.5.6
   Removing pip 1.3.1 from easy-install.pth file
   Adding pip 1.5.6 to easy-install.pth file
   Installing pip-script.py script to E:\Projects\FlaskEnv27\Scripts
   Installing pip.exe script to E:\Projects\FlaskEnv27\Scripts
   Installing pip.exe.manifest script to E:\Projects\FlaskEnv27\Scripts
   Installing pip3.4-script.py script to E:\Projects\FlaskEnv27\Scripts
   Installing pip3.4.exe script to E:\Projects\FlaskEnv27\Scripts
   Installing pip3.4.exe.manifest script to E:\Projects\FlaskEnv27\Scripts
   Installing pip3-script.py script to E:\Projects\FlaskEnv27\Scripts
   Installing pip3.exe script to E:\Projects\FlaskEnv27\Scripts
   Installing pip3.exe.manifest script to E:\Projects\FlaskEnv27\Scripts

   Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages
   Processing dependencies for pip
   Finished processing dependencies for pip

Comment: Like you told that did not get any output and the cursor keeps on blinking, I have improved my answer, check again.